# Remove before character (like backspace)

Tags: php

I have some text like this: "I am a gaot[BS][BS][BS]oat"

And It should look like this: "I am a goat"

How can I use "[BS]" as 'backspace'? So remove the character before backspace.
I tried preg_replace but it replaced only 1 backspace.

Can someone help?

I tried this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/.{1}\[BS\]/', '', $text);
```

But this works only with 1 [BS].

Comment: Show us some code you've tried using. What was the regular expression you used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this that I can see.

The "easy but long" way:

```
do {
    $text = preg_replace("/.\[BS\]/","",$text,-1,$c);
} while($c);
```

The "voodoo shortcut" way:

```
$text = preg_replace("/.(?R)*\[BS\]/","",$text);
```

Comment: Who's rude? This user answered perfectly to my quiestion.